# Dependency injection: is it ok to create object from injected object?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am trying to get comfortable with the Depenceny Injection pattern. This very question is about "not lying about the API" and passing to the constructor EVERYTHING that is needed by the class to work.

I am refactoring some old code, and I see that in the constructor an object is instantiated, and then from this object another object is created, and both are stored in the object being instantiated.

It is python, but the concept is agnostic.

```
class Element(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._node = NodePath(...)
        self._subnode = self._node.attachNewNode('blablabla')
```

So, obviously the first NodePath instance has to be injected, but what about the subnode created by calling the method `attachNewNode` on the first node? should it be injected as well?

This would be just injecting the main node:

```
class Element(object):

    def __init__(self, node):
        self._node = node
        self._subnode = self._node.attachNewNode('blablabla')
```

And this injecting both nodes:

```
class Element(object):

    def __init__(self, node, subnode):
        self._node = node
        self._subnode = subnode
```

From the testability, it is obviously better the second, but if I keep doing that my constructors will get a little bit cumbersome, and I have the feeling it may not be right.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on the nature of `node`, but if, for a moment, we assume no Leaky Abstractions, and proper encapsulation, the `attachNewNode` method [looks like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) a side-effect free function.

If this is the case, calling `attachNewNode` in the constructor is just a form of caching. From a perspective of *basic correctness*, you could just as well not have done that, but then invoked it *when you need it*, instead of in the constructor.

However, in general, you [shouldn't call methods on your dependencies during construction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22563738/126014).